# What is wrong with my grep OR expression?

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I'm a new with `grep` complex expressions. 
I need to find in a big log file lines according to multiple conditions.
It should be between some time-stamps, let's say between `14:11:55` and `14:12:05`, should contain `HardwareMmonitorHandlerSubscriber` and `ERROR` strings.
I'm trying to use something like

```
grep (?=^.*(14:11:[5-9]|14:12:0[0-5]))(?=^.*HardwareMmonitorHandlerSubscriber) log.log
```

but it gives me an error even when I'm trying to combine 2 conditions

```
grep ^.*(14:11:[5-9]|14:12:0[0-5]) log.log
```

gives me `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token`('`
error and

```
grep ^.*14:11:[5-9]|^.*14:12:0[0-5] log.log
```

gives me

```
-bash: ^.*14:12:0[0-5]: command not found
```

error
I'm using it with `Cygwin` on my Windows 7 PC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be,

```
grep '^.*\(14:11:[5-9]\|14:12:0[0-5]\)' log.log
```

Comment: Thanks! And what's about more complex expression like `(?=^.*(14:11:[5-9]|14:12:0[0-5]))(?=^.*HardwareMmonitorHandlerSubscriber)`? I tried putting the \ before each `(` and `)` but got an error -bash: $'14:12:0[0-5]))(?=^.*HardwareMmonitorHandlerSubscriber) log.log\ngrep ^.*\\(14:11:[5-9]\\|14:12:0[0-5]\\)': command not found

Comment: @Eliyahu: that's because `|` is a special character for the shell.  You need to escape it by putting a backslash (\\) in front of `|`.

Comment: @Eliyahu i suggest you to use `\|` because sed won't support lookahead. `regex1.*regex2\|regex2.*regex1`

Comment: @AvinashRaj your answer works OK but it is partial for me since I finally need to apply the entire expression I mentioned in the beginning of my question. I already tried to apply it in the following way grep -E '^.*\(14:11:[5-9]\|14:12:0[0-5]\)' log.log | grep -E 'HardwareMmonitorHandlerSubscriber'
 but it presents no output .....

Comment: ya, if you use `-E` then you don't need to escape `|`. `grep -E '^.*(14:11:[5-9]|14:12:0[0-5])' log.log | grep -E 'HardwareMmonitorHandlerSubscriber'`

Comment: But why it presents me empty output? log file presents multiple lines containing both expressins I am seraching for

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand you

Comment: What exact command do you mean? As you can see my regex are not single word so regex1.*regex2 doesn't help me. I know the order of string in the lines so I don't need to add \|regex2.*regex1

Comment: `grep -E '^.*(14:11:[5-9]|14:12:0[0-5])' log.log | grep -E 'HardwareMmonitorHandlerSubscriber'`